# GRPC_ARG_KEEPALIVE_PERMIT_WITHOUT_CALLS for java servers?

Tags: java, grpc

I have a java gRPC server and a C++ client.

I would like to use [`GRPC_ARG_KEEPALIVE_PERMIT_WITHOUT_CALLS`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/keepalive.md) in my C++ Client. As far as I understand, the server has to activate this option, too. So how do I activate `GRPC_ARG_KEEPALIVE_PERMIT_WITHOUT_CALLS` in a java server?

In the current state, the Client gets disconnected (as expected) with the following error:

```
Received a GOAWAY with error code ENHANCE_YOUR_CALM and debug data equal to "too_many_pings"
```

Clients and servers are in a controlled environment and the number of clients is known. There is no danger of DDOS-ing the server. (This risk seems to be the main reason, why this feature is disabled by default.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is funny... you research for days, then finally post your question and few hours later you finally find the solution..
Here is what I had to change:

```
-        server = ServerBuilder
+        server = NettyServerBuilder
                 .forPort(port)
+                .permitKeepAliveWithoutCalls(true)
+                .permitKeepAliveTime(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                 .addService(this.queryService)
                 .addService(this.commandService)
                 .addService(this.subscriptionService)
                 .build();
```